# bazel build tensorflow lite failed

Tags: visual-c++, bazel, tensorflow-lite

I tried to build tensorflowlite using bazel. Used bazel 4.2.2 version, MSYS2 and Visual C++ build tools 2019. I gets the following error when build is executed (command: bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/lite:tensorflowlite). Can someone help me to resolve this?

```
    INFO: Options provided by the client:
  Inherited 'common' options: --isatty=1 --terminal_columns=120
INFO: Reading rc options for 'build' from c:\tensorflow-2.8.0\.bazelrc:
  Inherited 'common' options: --experimental_repo_remote_exec
INFO: Options provided by the client:
  'build' options: --python_path=C:/Python39/python.exe
INFO: Reading rc options for 'build' from c:\tensorflow-2.8.0\.bazelrc:
  'build' options: --define framework_shared_object=true --java_toolchain=@tf_toolchains//toolchains/java:tf_java_toolchain --host_java_toolchain=@tf_toolchains//toolchains/java:tf_java_toolchain --define=use_fast_cpp_protos=true --define=allow_oversize_protos=true --spawn_strategy=standalone -c opt --announce_rc --define=grpc_no_ares=true --noincompatible_remove_legacy_whole_archive --enable_platform_specific_config --define=with_xla_support=true --config=short_logs --config=v2 --define=no_aws_support=true --define=no_hdfs_support=true --experimental_cc_shared_library
INFO: Reading rc options for 'build' from c:\tensorflow-2.8.0\.tf_configure.bazelrc:
  'build' options: --action_env PYTHON_BIN_PATH=C:/Python39/python.exe --action_env PYTHON_LIB_PATH=C:/Python39/lib/site-packages --python_path=C:/Python39/python.exe --copt=/d2ReducedOptimizeHugeFunctions --host_copt=/d2ReducedOptimizeHugeFunctions --define=override_eigen_strong_inline=true
INFO: Reading rc options for 'build' from c:\tensorflow-2.8.0\.bazelrc:
  'build' options: --deleted_packages=tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/benchmarks,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/jit/python_binding,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/jit/transforms,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/python_tests,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests/analysis,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests/jit,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests/lhlo_to_tfrt,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests/tf_to_corert,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests/tf_to_tfrt_data,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests/saved_model,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/transforms/lhlo_gpu_to_tfrt_gpu,tensorflow/core/runtime_fallback,tensorflow/core/runtime_fallback/conversion,tensorflow/core/runtime_fallback/kernel,tensorflow/core/runtime_fallback/opdefs,tensorflow/core/runtime_fallback/runtime,tensorflow/core/runtime_fallback/util,tensorflow/core/tfrt/common,tensorflow/core/tfrt/eager,tensorflow/core/tfrt/eager/backends/cpu,tensorflow/core/tfrt/eager/backends/gpu,tensorflow/core/tfrt/eager/core_runtime,tensorflow/core/tfrt/eager/cpp_tests/core_runtime,tensorflow/core/tfrt/fallback,tensorflow/core/tfrt/gpu,tensorflow/core/tfrt/run_handler_thread_pool,tensorflow/core/tfrt/runtime,tensorflow/core/tfrt/saved_model,tensorflow/core/tfrt/saved_model/tests,tensorflow/core/tfrt/tpu,tensorflow/core/tfrt/utils
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:short_logs in file c:\tensorflow-2.8.0\.bazelrc: --output_filter=DONT_MATCH_ANYTHING
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:v2 in file c:\tensorflow-2.8.0\.bazelrc: --define=tf_api_version=2 --action_env=TF2_BEHAVIOR=1
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:windows in file c:\tensorflow-2.8.0\.bazelrc: --copt=/W0 --copt=/D_USE_MATH_DEFINES --host_copt=/D_USE_MATH_DEFINES --cxxopt=/std:c++14 --host_cxxopt=/std:c++14 --config=monolithic --copt=-DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN --host_copt=-DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN --copt=-DNOGDI --host_copt=-DNOGDI --copt=/experimental:preprocessor --host_copt=/experimental:preprocessor --linkopt=/DEBUG --host_linkopt=/DEBUG --linkopt=/OPT:REF --host_linkopt=/OPT:REF --linkopt=/OPT:ICF --host_linkopt=/OPT:ICF --verbose_failures --features=compiler_param_file --distinct_host_configuration=false
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:monolithic in file c:\tensorflow-2.8.0\.bazelrc: --define framework_shared_object=false
INFO: Analyzed target //tensorflow/lite:tensorflowlite (71 packages loaded, 2615 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: C:/users/code/_bazel_ryan/fvoo5v2n/external/flatbuffers/src/BUILD:40:11: Compiling src/idl_gen_rust.cpp failed: (Exit 1): cl.exe failed: error executing command
  cd C:/users/code/_bazel_ryan/fvoo5v2n/execroot/org_tensorflow
  SET INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt;
    SET PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\x64\;;C:\Windows\system32
    SET PWD=/proc/self/cwd
    SET PYTHON_BIN_PATH=C:/Python39/python.exe
    SET PYTHON_LIB_PATH=C:/Python39/lib/site-packages
    SET RUNFILES_MANIFEST_ONLY=1
    SET TEMP=C:\Users\CODE\AppData\Local\Temp
    SET TF2_BEHAVIOR=1
    SET TMP=C:\Users\CODE\AppData\Local\Temp
  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/amd64/cl.exe @bazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/external/flatbuffers/src/_objs/flatc/idl_gen_rust.obj.params
Execution platform: @local_execution_config_platform//:platform
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/experimental:preprocessor'
fatal error C1007: unrecognized flag '-ReducedOptimizeHugeFunctions' in 'p2'
Target //tensorflow/lite:tensorflowlite failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 21.879s, Critical Path: 4.57s
INFO: 60 processes: 60 internal.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Comment: Hi check a github repo with some useful colab notebooks
https://github.com/farmaker47/Build_TensorFlow_Lite_Support_Library_With_Docker
also a medium post
https://farmaker47.medium.com/building-tensorflow-lite-support-library-with-docker-1e0ac0abda7